# Yii list view update on radio button selection

Tags: yii

In a model have 4 fields. id, name, address, status. In the list view showing a radio button list for displaying status. In the Listview i want to update the list based on the radio button selection. How it possible in Yii?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by:

```
array(
        'header' => 'Status',
        'name' => 'status',
        'value' => '($data->status == 0) ? "Yes" : "No"'
    ),
```

in the view file CGridview widget:like this

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'users-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array( array(
    'header' => 'Status',
    'name' => 'status',
    'value' => '($data->status == 0) ? "Yes" : "No"'
),`
```